# Declarations required to iterate over an array of arrays of pointers to instances in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, arduino, declaration

Firstly, I'm targeting the Arduino here. Please do **NOT** suggest I use STL, Boost or any other kind of library, or anything that requires `new` or `malloc()`. It's not practical for my case.

I have a bunch of arrays of pointers to `Foo` instances, declared thus:

```
Foo *group0[] = { &foo0, &foo1, &foo2};
Foo *group1[] = { &foo3, &foo4, &foo5};
Foo *group2[] = { &foo6, &foo7, &foo8};
```

How do I declare an array of these groups, and iterate over it?

(I understand arrays, for loops and pointers in general, but the C++ syntax for the declarations is doing my head in.)

Comment: In general, I find it easiest to write non-trivial C declarations and references using [cdecl](http://cdecl.org/)

Comment: I tried that and couldn't even get it to understand me :-P.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code creates an array of your groups and then iterates through it, invoking a call to a Foo method for each of your instantiations (foo[0-8]). It makes a few assumptions about the contents of the arrays involved (namely the bounds on i and j), but it should do for the example, and should be easy enough to customize to your liking:

```
#include <iostream>

// Example Foo class (instantiated with foo[0-8]).
class Foo
{
    public:

        Foo(int x)
        {
            bar = x;
        }

        void FooMethod()
        {
            std::cout << bar << std::endl;
        }

    private:

        int bar;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Instantiate foo[0-8].
    Foo foo0 = Foo(0);
    Foo foo1 = Foo(1);
    Foo foo2 = Foo(2);
    Foo foo3 = Foo(3);
    Foo foo4 = Foo(4);
    Foo foo5 = Foo(5);
    Foo foo6 = Foo(6);
    Foo foo7 = Foo(7);
    Foo foo8 = Foo(8);

    // Declare Foo group arrays of, type Foo*.
    Foo* group0[] = { &foo0, &foo1, &foo2 };
    Foo* group1[] = { &foo3, &foo4, &foo5 };
    Foo* group2[] = { &foo6, &foo7, &foo8 };

    // Declare Foo* group array to hold Foo groups, of type Foo**.
    Foo** groups[] = { group0, group1, group2 };

    // Iterate through Foo groups and over each individual Foo object.
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
        {
            // Do something with Foo (i.e. invoke its member method).
            groups[i][j]->FooMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

I hope that this answers your question. Let me know if it doesn't, and I'll see what I can do :)

Comment: Thanks for the accepted answer! I hope this solved your problem.

Comment: You totally win with a) an example that demonstrates you understood what I was asking, b) answers the question I asked, c) compiles d) comes with output that proves it works. Bloody rare situation on C++ syntax questions. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As groupX have the same size, you may use :

```
using type = Foo* (*)[3];
type b[3] = {&group0, &group1, &group2};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Foo** list[] = {group0, group1, group2};
Foo** pGroup;

for(int i = 0; 3 < i; ++i)
{
  pGroup = list[i]; // Ptr to one of the groups
}
```

And then just dereference pGroup to get at the group elements